# Java JFileChooser wont die

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I have game program where I want the player to choose the file directory to save his game. I am using `JFileChooser` for this works perfectly fine but it won't close.

here is the code:

```
    public NewGameState(Game game) {
    super(game);

    open = new JButton();
    fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    fc.setDialogTitle("Choose file for the new world");
    fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

}

public void tick() {

    input();
    selection();
}

public void render(Graphics g) {

    drawSelection(g);
    drawGUI(g);
}

private void input(){

    if(game.getKeyManager().up){

        selection --;
    }else if(game.getKeyManager().down){

        selection ++;
    }

    if(game.getKeyManager().space){

        if(selection == 0){

            fileChooser();      //calling fileChooser method when pressing space
        }else if(selection == 1){

        }else if(selection == 2){


        }
    }
}

private void selection(){
    //blahbahabahaa
    }
}

//fileChooser
private void fileChooser(){

    fc.showOpenDialog(null);
}
```

I thought that space is true and it keeps executing the code every tick it turn out it won't stop reading the code which stops the ticking proccess. It keeps reading the method over and over. Other answers are using panel which I'm not using panel in this program I'm using `canvas` and `jframe` only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is what you are looking for just to be able to close the File Chooser Dialog after selecting the file or saving the file. Just still try to make the code more explanatory i think this should based on my understanding of what u explained

```
 int c = fileWindow.showSaveDialog(this);
        if(c==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            files.append(fileWindow.getSelectedFile()+"\n");
```